# scala: overriding a value of generic, existential type with a concretised type

Tags: scala, generics, existential-type

I have a generic trait MappingPath, invariant regarding it's type parameters:

```
trait MappingPath[X<:AnyMapping, Y<:AnyMapping]
```

and an interface of a factory for it:

```
trait Pathfinder[X, Y] {
    def apply(fun :X=>Y) :MappingPath[_<:AnyMapping,_<:AnyMapping]
    def get(fun :X=>Y) :Option[MappingPath[_<:AnyMapping, _<:AnyMapping]]
}
```

I start a skeleton implementation which works for a single mapping:

```
class MappingPathfinder[M<:AnyMapping, X, Y] extends Pathfinder[X, Y] {
   override def apply(fun :X=>Y) :MappingPath[M, _<:AnyMapping] = ???
   override def get(fun :X=>Y) :Option[MappingPath[M, _<:AnyMapping]] = ???
}
```

which produces a compile error complaining that `MappingPathfinder.apply` overrides nothing and doesn't implement `Pathfinder.apply`. What's interesting, replacing `M` with `_<:AnyMapping` in `apply`'s return type makes it compile, and no complaints are made regarding similar `get` method.

What's going on? I use scala 2.11.5.

EDIT:
I was able to circumvene my problem by adding explicit existantial annotations:

```
//Pathfinder
def apply(fun :X=>Y) :MappingPath[A, B] forSome { type A<:AnyMapping; type B<:AnyMapping }

//MappingPathfinder
def apply(fun :X=>Y) :MappingPath[A, B] forSome { type A>:M<:M; type B<:AnyMapping }
```

It seems to work, i.e
I can do:

```
(p :MappingPath[_<:AnyMapping, M]) ++ mappingPathfinder(f),
```

where `++` requires a path starting with the exact same type as `this` ends. It looks a bit silly and certainly confusing though.

Comment: Afaik, `def apply(): MappingPath[_<: AnyMapping, _ <: AnyMapping]` is identical to `def apply[A <: AnyMapping, B <: AnyMapping](): MappingPath[A, B]`. Looking at it like this, we can see that the signature `def apply[B <: AnyMapping](): MappingPath[M, B]` doesn't match. However, those existential types are really confusing me and I cannot figure out why `get` compiles. If you're just looking for a solution, I'd say don't use existential types but parameterize `PathFinder` with `M <: AnyMapping`.

Comment: It is really equivalent? In the expanded form, the caller can specify result specialisation, while I expected (or at least wanted) to return a truly ..[T] forSome { type T }. It is certainly possible to have a member declaration of Seq[_] in parent type and override it to Seq[T], where T is overriding class type parameter and that's what I wanted here.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but your use case can be simplified to:

```
trait Higher[U]

trait Super {
  def foo: Higher[_]
}

trait Sub[M] {
  override def foo: Higher[M]  // error: method foo overrides nothing
}
```

---

Instead of existential types, I would use a type member:

```
trait Super {
  type U
  def foo: Higher[U]
}

trait Sub[M] {
  type U = M
}
```

I think the difference is that in the case of the existential type, you only specify that the type parameter returned has some upper bound, but not necessarily that it is always *the same type*; whereas in my second example, `type U` means this will eventually be *one specific type*, and you can only *refine a specific type*. You can make upper bounds more precise:

```
trait Upper

trait A {
  type U <: Upper  
}

trait Specific extends Upper

trait B extends A {
  type U <: Specific   // type is "overridden"
}
```

If it's possible, I would avoid existential types, and your case seems a perfect fit for such avoidance. Most of the time, existential types are only needed for Java interop.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when in sub I override the upper bound by a member type equal to type parameter, whenever I'll use sub directly, the upper bound will be different  for all instances of MappingPathfinder[M] parameterized with the same type (even different references of the same instance) if that type is abstract at the point of use due to how path dependent types work. It might not be a problem for me in this particular case, but in general, abstract type members are a huge pain to work with for this reason.